# Разделить двумерный массив на два вектора

Tags: python, массивы

Имеется таблица в виде массива, где по первому индексу `my_array[i][0]` получаем id, `my_array[i][1]` по второму наименование. Нужно разделить его на два отдельных массива: один с именами, другой с id. Решение, которое пришло в голову:

```
id = []
names = []
for item in my_array:
    id.append(item[0])
    names.append(item[1])
```

Возможно ли реализовать это проще, без цикла по всему массиву?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то например так:

```
id, names = list(zip(*my_array))[:2]
```

P.S.: Если вас интересует производительность, то стоит обратить внимание на `numpy` и т.п.